# Why is the reason that MediaElement doesn't play any sound

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, mediaelement

This the code which I'm having problems:

```
MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
media.Source = new Uri("/ding.wav", UriKind.Relative);
media.Play();
```

The folder where contains that code is the same for the sound. I mean, they are in the same folder. And the build action from the file is RESOURCE.

It doesn't play any sound. What's happening?

Comment: OK, ahm is there another option to play sound?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
MediaElement media = new MediaElement();
media.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
media.UnloadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
media.Source = new Uri("ding.wav", UriKind.Relative);
media.Play();
```

Note: When I tried, I had Build Action set to `Content` and Copy to Output Directory to `"Copy Always"` for ding.wav.

Comment: Here's [LoadedBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.loadedbehavior.aspx) and here's [UnloadedBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.unloadedbehavior.aspx)

Comment: Silverlight doesn't have LoadedBehavior / UnloadedBehavior btw.